# can you use jade to only render the dynamic part of your html...and not mess with rest of your html

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Or can you render partially and render rest later. So lets say when app starts up it renders most of the html. But when user abc wants to see his profile jade renders name to abc and merge it with regular pre rendered html and then you send it etc.

Rendering whole html pages at every request seems like a waste.

Converting all static html to jade seems like a annoyance that can be avoided. Slowly css became LESS and html became JADE?

I am lost on how to use jade I am learning express.

Comment: is there some plugin/middleware that parse html and find where jade goes, compile it insert it and return that html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jade's `compileClient` function to create a function that will render predefined Jade code on the fly. ([See the API reference.](http://jade-lang.com/api/))

So, if you create a Jade file with the dynamic HTML, and compile that for the client, you can then call that function at a later time, and insert the resulting HTML string to the DOM.

Comment: is there a way i could define inside html 'Here goes dynamic jade compiled file'